# Is there anyway to stop collapsible side navigation to stop jumping on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code works except it keeps jumping every time I load or refresh the page and I was wondering if anyone knows of a good solution to this? Any help much appreciated.

Press the 'Run' button on this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DjbeK/) to see what I mean.

```
            <div id="sideNav_header">Navigation</div>

            <ul id="collapsibleMenu">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 1.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 1.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 2.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 3.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 4.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List Item 5.3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


//Script//
     $("#collapsibleMenu > li > a").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);

                // Expand or collapse:
                $("#collapsibleMenu > li > a").click(function() {
                    $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("slow");
                });​
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, change:

```
$("#collapsibleMenu > li > a").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
```

to:

```
$("#collapsibleMenu > li > a").find("+ ul").slideUp(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DjbeK/1/

Using `slideUp(1)` on page load doesn't make sense you can use `hide()` instead.

Comment: Tried it with .slideUp(0) and .hide(0) but it still jerks up every time I load the page. I might try and find a css based solution. Thanks though.

Comment: @Matt you are welcome, yes, in this case CSS is the best option.